# C++ runtime, display exception message

Tags: c++, exception

I am using gcc on linux to compile C++ code.
There are some exceptions which should not be handled and should close program.
However, I would like to be able to display exception string:

For example:

`throw std::runtime_error(" message");` does not display message, only type of error.
I would like to display messages as well.
Is there way to do it?

it is a library, I really do not want to put catch statements and let library user decide.
However, right now library user is fortran, which does not allow to handle exceptions.
in principle, I can put handlers in wrapper code, but rather not to if there is a way around

Comment: `throw std::runtime_error(" message");` now shows the message on g++ 6.2.0, Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 Thanks! Clean and minimal effort.

Comment: @CiroSantilli冠状病毒审查六四事件法轮功 pretty sure this is the only commend actually addressing the question properly. I think this should be the answer.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanShoman done!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Standard exceptions have a virtual `what()` method that gives you the message associated with the exception:

```
int main() {
   try {
       // your stuff
   }
   catch( const std::exception & ex ) {
       cerr << ex.what() << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: I put clarifications about my requirements

Comment: @aaa If your code is intended to be used from non-C++ code, it should be given C linkage and should never allow exceptions to escape into the calling code.

Comment: what is a good way to communicate terminal problems into main program?
I need some facility to print error string, without relying on fortran output

Comment: @aaa It's the fortran program's responsibility to decide if a problem is terminal, not the C++ libraries. There are lots of solutions to this, (store the error state in a static variable & provide an API to access it, for example) but letting an exception escape into the fortran code is not acceptable.

Comment: Return error codes via your C Linkage interface, and provide your library users a method to convert those error codes into strings.

Comment: @Mark one potential problem I could have would be due to multithreading in C++ code. I will have to think of something.

Comment: There is a small typo in your answer. I should be ex.what(). You forgot the x.

Comment: When I throw a std::runtime_error and catch a std::exception what() says "std::exception". When I throw a std::runtime_error and catch a std::runtime_error, what() says the error message I placed into runtime error.

Answer (score 8):

You could write in main:

```
try{

}catch(const std::exception &e){
   std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
   throw;
}
```

Comment: I put some clarifications.
In principle I can go with something like this if there is no way around it

Comment: And note that this has the downside of blowing away your callstack which g++ would normally preserve in the core file for uncaught exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `try/catch` block and `throw;` statement to let library user to handle the exception. `throw;` statement passes control to another handler for the same exception.

Comment: okay, I think I will put try catch with message print in fortran/c wrappers and throw from there. then I will let C++ interface handle exceptions on its own

Answer (score 3):

**GCC shows the message at least since 6.2.0**

I had tested it on g++ 6.2.0, Ubuntu 16.10, and now again in g++ 9.3.0 Ubuntu 20.04, and both showed the message, not sure when behavior changed:

```
#include <stdexcept>

void myfunc() {
    throw std::runtime_error("my message");
}

int main() {
    myfunc();
}
```

compile and run:

```
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp
./main.out
```

output containing the `my message` error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  my message
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend making an adapter for your library for fortran callers.  Put your try/catch in the adapter. Essentially your library needs multiple entry points if you want it to be called from fortran (or C) but still allow exceptions to propigate to C++ callers.  This way also has the advantage of giving C++ linkage to C++ callers.  Only having a fortran interface will limit you substantially in that everything must be passed by reference, you need to account for hidden parameters for char * arguments etc.